# Missing Functionality after loading WSDL in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, api, soap, wsdl, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to implement a connection to DB Schenker in C# using Visual Studio 2019. However, after loading the WSDL in Visual Studio 2019, there was no way to create a response object like I was used to. (e.g response = webclient(registration, orderdetails)) I noticed that Visual Studio had not converted all operations to functions. The getBookingRequestLand() and getBookingResponseLand() functions are missing and probably others.

Is it possible that Visual Studio did not fully translate the WSDL into code? How can I create a request?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/net-framework/creating-the-web-service-proxy?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

please check their is any "operation" tag name related "getBookingResponseLand"

example : https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl

have Method name "NDFDgenByDayLatLonList" so its looking like

```
<operation name="NDFDgenByDayLatLonList">
<documentation>Returns National Weather Service digital weather forecast data. Supports latitudes and longitudes for the Continental United States, Hawaii, Guam, and Puerto Rico only. The latitude and longitude are delimited by a comma and multiple pairs are delimited by a space (i.e. 30.00,-77.00 40.00,-90.00). Allowable values for the input variable "format" are "24 hourly" and "12 hourly". The input variable "startDate" is a date string representing the first day (Local) of data to be returned. The input variable "numDays" is the integer number of days for which the user wants data. Allowable values for the input variable "Unit" are "e" for U.S. Standare/English units and "m" for Metric units.</documentation>
<input message="tns:NDFDgenByDayLatLonListRequest"/>
<output message="tns:NDFDgenByDayLatLonListResponse"/>
</operation>
```

Some time operation element with namespace

```
<wsdl:operation name="getSearchKeywordsRecommendation">
            <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services/getSearchKeywordsRecommendation"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body
                    use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body
                    use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
```

If you are using VS2019 you can simply click on the service and select "Update..."

**STEPS**
To update a project Web reference

1. In Solution Explorer, open your project's App_WebReferences folder and click the node for the Web reference you want to update.
2. Right-click the reference and click Update Web Reference.

The new files for the XML Web service are downloaded to your project. Information for the XML Web service is updated within your project.

[image]

Comment: I have added the wsdl to the question, for me it seems like  tags are ok

Comment: please see again there is no operation name found of "getBookingResponseLand"  <operation name="getBookingResponseLand">

Comment: I think it be not publicly accessible ?

Comment: sadly it`s not.

Answer (score 0):

I was incapacitated =(. You have to create a client which contains an interface which then contains the request method, then you can create a request. Assign this to a variable and you have a response object.